# SQL variable #4 data type GETDATE

Tags: sql-server

It is stating that variable #4 is having a problem. I can tell its the GETDATE but when I do GETDATE() it says invalid syntax. Any ideas?

I tried using DATETIME as well, but the problem with that one is it kept leaving NULL values in my table.

I have tried doing GETDATE() but past that my knowledge on the subject is very small.

```
ALTER TABLE Products
ADD
ProductPrice decimal(3,2) default((9.99)) not null,
ProductAdded GETDATE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting `GETDATE()` into parentheses, as you have already done for the other decimal default value:

```
ALTER TABLE Products
ADD
ProductPrice DECIMAL(3,2) DEFAULT((9.99)) NOT NULL,
ProductAdded DEFAULT (GETDATE());
```